# Blender Geo nodes: how to populate a curve with different assets for the edges

Tags: geometry-nodes

i am totaly lost and cant figure this out:
I want to arrange assets along a curve (or edges of a mesh) and exchange the corners with premade corner assets.. it would be nice if the assets strech to a certain amount to fill the whole curve (if the lenght of the curve does not evenly divide by the lenght of the asset..
I manages to detect the curves angles but just cant figure out how to place the "filling" aset.. any help woud be awesome!

and a screenshot of what i want to achive:
[image]

and the blend file:
[image]

Comment: on the sketch two elements overlap on the 45° angle - is it really what you want?

Comment: yea.. its a stupi scetch.. no i just want to figure out how to fill the empty segmets with meshes.. like the regular array modifier for each spline segment .. so that it lines up with the corner parts (wich are for now 90/270 degrees..but if it works right it should be possible to also exchange the 45 degree part..)

Comment: the goal i want to achive is to distribute balkony parts along a mesh edge or spline.. its imoprtant that the edges stay at theire place and the rest juts gets filled with the "standart" parts (they can be streched a bit to fill the curve if needed or just leave a start part empty ..aslong as the edges are conected properly....) its for a architectual project.. i can figure out the math but without a for loop im lost and i think its possible even before blender 4.0...